# How to pass some data to a running thread in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-pthread

So let's say I create a thread and detach it from the main process, and start it.

So, after the thread is detached, how is it possible to pass some chunks of data like `strings`, or `int`s to the already running thread?

*Edit*
What I am basically doing is trying to implement the WS protocol:

```
<?php
// Pseudo-Code
class LongRunningThread extends \Thread {
    private $handshakeReq;

    public function __construct(Request $handshakeRequest) {
        $this->handshakeReq = $handshakeRequest;
    }

    public function run() {
        // Do handshake
        // But do not exit, because after the handshake is done the socket connection needs to be maintained.
        // Probably some trigger which notifies that a new message is here and the message arrives <automagically>
        if(trigger) {
            $message = $message;
            $this->onNewWsMessage($message);
        }
    }

    public function onNewWsMessage(string $rawMessage) {
        // Process the message...
    }
}

$stream = stream_socket_server(sprintf("tcp://%s:%d",
    "localhost",
    1337
), $errno, $errmsg);

// Boiler plate, and connection acceptance (blah blah blah)
// $client is the the accepted connection
$message = fread($client, 4096);

// Cannot pass the $client in here because the instability of resources with threads
// as passing them here, apparently converts them to <bool> false
$longRunningThread = new \LongRunningThread($message);
$longRunningThread->start() && $longRunningThread->join();
```

<sub>I found various answers related to passing data to a running thread, but I couldn't find any specifically for `PHP`.</sub>

<sub>I am using [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The actual question is quite vague.
What you want to do falls to my understanding under the IPC (interprocess communication) and can be implemented with a couple of ways (to my knowledge the most common one is :http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-pair.php).
I would suggest though that you could use some kind of queueing and polling system like [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) to pass around messages.It will provide some overhead but its a well known and highly used solution

Comment: Have added some code in there ;-) could you explain the things a bit about the links given in the answer =)